# Typesafe event args for event emitter

Tags: typescript

I am dealing with an emitter that looks like this:

```
emitEvent(eventName: string, eventArgs: IEventArgs): void
```

IEventArgs is a general-purpose interface, since I want it to be possible to write quick-and-dirty event:

```
export interface IEventArgsBase {
  senderId: string;
}

export interface IEventArgs extends IEventArgsBase {
  [key: string ]: any;
}
```

However, for established events, I have specific interfaces, like:

```
export interface IEventArgsMyEvent extends IEventArgsBase {
  someArg: string;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve (without re-architecting the whole event system) is:

1. Type emitEvent such that for known event names, it requires a specific eventArgs interface. E.g., if you pass "MyEvent" to eventName, you must also pass IEventArgsMyEvent.
2. If you pass an unknown event name (you are firing a new, quick-and-dirty event) then IEventArgs is fine - it should be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Canonically you can do something like this with an overload, but the hazard is that as long as you can pass any string with an arbitrary map of IEventArgs, there's no incentive for Typescript to apply the more restrictive overload.

```js
declare function emitEvent(
    eventName: "spawned", eventArgs: IEventArgsSpawned): void;
declare function emitEvent(
    eventName: string, eventArgs: IEventArgs): void;

function yourFunction()  {
  // "spawned"-specific overload works and is typed well
  emitEvent("spawned", {senderId: "blah", loc: [0, 0, 0], rot: [1, 1, 1]});

  // default overload works as well
  emitEvent("foo", {senderId: "blah", bar: "baz"});

  // but if the properties are missing, the other overload
  // unfortunately still works
  emitEvent("spawned", {senderId: "blah", propertiesAre: "missing"});
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=19&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxAFssMBRANxFQwAoRLqA5KQkALngCIBnABygDuqEME4AaAgwwBBGAHNuHAJIUqM+dwDK-ISICUHcjizAA3AChQkWAhTpseAsTJS6U5qw7cMMLKjkS9GqyCsqq1CHcBvBGJhbmIAAevDgwGPB+GCAwiFBgCCpSkQBCUNwIAN7m8PDlqKAwSsBePn5yFgC+5uYYAJ68BQBq4BipAMzwALzwANqoyIQARtkS80sr8GvLMAC68UkpaRnU2bn58IXBGgSJWfXcF+HqCqXl8FU1MwDWIL0tvv54DsOFBUL1Ot0Dql0plTnkCk9ItpBMJgDc7sAHpcIhpXpVqvAIDgwMphphxhYajAcBhSSMKeYuuY7JhcPhejhkDAAGJoVl4Gh6GofeAAelFXD4KJEnAAtHxwFhEFgwPAcJQYESoGiBKkvg9QWisA8+gMdSAIBACUQSE8aDwdKjxO86g0mhxOItoAALZ1EkmzAAMEmD8EDOwk1NpswAjBI4-AYzsOnp4jVxfBQLlkBB0urslqdXqDQ8BBarTUbS41PbEDgcM6Kq7su6uF6oL6JItYB7uwAvTgptNiiWLZAwxDwDDehC8akDNJYEAGuDwYjcbhtCTThA0mcwNUawvwNB1tJoKBZCC9WrYS3wXUwfXW5x2h3S0QSJtUN3NNs+505xwBdsGXWR2C4ddN38QdU0ZIA)

If you want to be able to pass an arbitrary event name with arbitrary args, it will be difficult to convince Typescript that known events like "spawned" should not follow the same pattern. That said, you have these workarounds and upgrades:

- Avoid the overload syntax by [using an event map](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.3.2/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L2159-L2168) in a similar way to [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.3.2/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L2201-L2202): the map expresses which string results in which Event, and the generic `addEventListener` consumes it. Note that lib.dom.d.ts uses those for adding listeners, but [`dispatchEvent`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.3.2/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5423) takes an `Event` object without overloads or specification: it's no model for you there.
- If you can, give the `emitEvent` a different method name for your quick-and-dirty events, or use a [branded type](https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/) with a helper method to wrap your quick-and-dirty events to convince TypeScript it can't swap easily between your default vs specific overloads.

Comment: Is it possible to define the overloads in some more programmatic way? It'd be nice to derive them from a map or something so I'm not stacking 50 overloads on top of the emitter.

Comment: @samueldcorbin I've updated the answer to add a reference to "EventMap", which is a pattern you can observe in the builtin [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v4.3.2/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).